# Grouping case expressions in elm (0.18)

Tags: elm, case-statement

Is there a way in elm (0.18) to group together a series of case expressions that do the same thing?

For example:

```
type Character
    = Sleepy
    | Happy
    | Grumpy
    | Dopey
    | Sneezy
    | Bashful
    | Doc
    | SnowWhite
    | Queen


getKindOfCharacter : Character -> String
getKindOfCharacter character =
  case character of
    (Sleepy | Happy | Grumpy | Dopey | Sneezy | Bashful | Doc) ->
      "Dwarf"
    SnowWhite ->
      "Hero"
    Queen ->
      "Villain"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, but you can refactor your types as follows:

```
type Character
    = Dwaft Dwarf
    | SnowWhite
    | Queen

type Dwarf
    = Sleepy
    | Happy
    | Grumpy
    | Dopey
    | Sneezy
    | Bashful
    | Doc

getKindOfCharacter : Character -> String
getKindOfCharacter character =
  case character of
    Dwarf _ ->
      "Dwarf"
    SnowWhite ->
      "Hero"
    Queen ->
      "Villain"
```

Or even better...

```
type Character
    = Dwaft Dwarf
    | Hero Hero
    | Villain Villain

type Dwarf
    = Sleepy
    | Happy
    | Grumpy
    | Dopey
    | Sneezy
    | Bashful
    | Doc

type Hero
    = SnowWhite

type Villain
    = Queen
```

Then you woudn't need the `getKindOfCharacter` function because the `Character` type would provide the same info.

```
let 
    hero : Character
    hero = Hero SnowWhite

    villain : Character
    villain = Villain Queen

    dwarf : Character
    dwarf = Dwarf Dopey
in
    ...
```